# Vue.js - How to have isolated scope for a spinner inside of `v-for`

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

### HTML

```
<div v-for="account in accounts">
  ...
  <button v-if="!isUnlinking" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" @click="unlinkAccount(provider.providerId)">
      <i class="fa fa-unlink"></i>
      Unlink
  </button>

  <button v-if="!!isUnlinking" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" :disabled="!!isUnlinking">
      <i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i>
      Unlinking...
  </button>
  ...
</div>
```

### PROBLEM

When I click on `Unlink button`, the button within all *repeated/iterated* `div` elements is getting the `spinner`.  Whereas I would like only the `button` that is *clicked* to have the *spinner* icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I would like to propose to my question:

## UPDATE `NOV-2018`:

I would suggest creating a new `vue-component` and iterate over it.  The account object would be passed to the `child-component` via   `props`:

```
<div>
  <h3> Accounts </h3>
  <AccountButton v-for="account in accounts" :account="account" />
</div>
```

Good Luck...

---

#### PREVIOUS SUGGESTION

```
<div v-for="account in accounts.map(function(item){ return {item: item, isUnlinking: false}})">
  ...
  <button v-if="!account.isUnlinking" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" @click="unlinkAccount(account)">
      <i class="fa fa-unlink"></i>
      Unlink
  </button>

  <button v-if="!!account.isUnlinking" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" :disabled="!!account.isUnlinking">
      <i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i>
      Unlinking...
  </button>
  ...
</div>


<script>
  // somewhere inside Vue.component
  ...
  function unlinkAccount(account) {
    account.isUnlinking = true;
    // do the unlinking with account.item.provider.providerId
  }
  ...
</script>
```

Here, I've bootstrapped a new array from the existing `accounts` array with the `map` function (*this mapping could be moved into the Vue component syntax in JS instead of keeping it in HTML*).  Now each `account item` has its own property `isUnlinking` which can be set as required.  I've set the initial value to `false` as `unlinking` will start only after clicking the button.

Thank you @Bazinga, @Saurabh, @Bernard Doci and @M U for your participation

Good Luck...

Answer (score 2):

In your V-FOR, each row can be assigned a key.

Eg.

```
<div v-for=" (b,key) in buttons">

  <button>
  {{b}}
  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" @click="clickButton(key)" v-if="buttonsLoading[key]"> 
  </button>

</div>
```

And in your VUE data section:

```
data: {
    buttons:{
        button1:'Click me',
        button2:'NO click me,
        button3:'NOOO Click me',
    },
    buttonsLoading:[],
},
methods: {
    clickButton:function(key)
    {
          Vue.set(this.buttonsLoading , key , 1);
    }
}
```

You're obviously going to know when the button needs to stop, if you're doing an axios or ajax request so when you get a success response, add  `Vue.set(this.buttonsLoading , 'button' + key , 0)` so it stops spinning.

Eg. in my V-FOR setup, I have a button in each row.
When clicked, each individual button must act separately and show it's own spinner, not all of them (which is the error you are having).

To do this, you must create an array and then you can set the key to the array when clicked.

Did a video for you if you want, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zm00rS0gX24, please excuse if it is not explained exactly, I am not the best at explaining these things :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In this case every button should have `id` parameter. When you are 'unlinking' you have to check with `v-if` if id of button is the same as context element and display spinner only in this case.

Comment: won't that result in **multiple** ids in HTML which is *not* a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to me is you are using single variable `isUnlinking` to make all the buttons visible, so if the variable changes for one of the button, it is applied on all the buttons.

You have to have a array of `isUnlinking` and change only for that button, like following:

```
<div v-for="(account, index) in accounts">
  ...
  <button v-if="!isUnlinking[index]" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" @click="unlinkAccount(provider.providerId)">
      <i class="fa fa-unlink"></i>
      Unlink
  </button>

  <button v-else class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" :disabled="isUnlinking[index]">
      <i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i>
      Unlinking...
  </button>
```

Also notice the use of [v-else](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-else), instead of `v-if="!!isUnlinking"`.

...

Comment: how will the `unlinking Array` know how many items are there in the `v-for list`?  And thanks for `v-else`...it's cool

Comment: @Akash You will have to initialise the array using `accounts` array and set it false initially.

Comment: it feels little *cumbersome* to simultaneously **initialize** an array with `false booleans`.  I am considering writing a `component` for this `button` which will have its `own scope`.  Moreover, when an account is *unlinked* i will have to also *delete* that `array row`.  it could get *complicated*

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add this property on the account object:

```
<div v-for="account in accounts">
  ...
  <button v-if="!account.isUnlinking" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" @click="unlinkAccount(provider.providerId)">
      <i class="fa fa-unlink"></i>
      Unlink
  </button>

  <button v-if="!!account.isUnlinking" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" :disabled="!!isUnlinking">
      <i class="fa fa-spin fa-refresh"></i>
      Unlinking...
  </button>
  ...
</div>
```

Now it's bound to the specific object.

Comment: that's a good idea, however, mutating the `account` object is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

One way I have solved similar problem was that I have passed $event.target.children[0] as a property on a click event function, than removed the class from  element and appended a new class for a spinner to an  element. I hope this will help.

```
<div v-for="account in accounts">
  <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" 
    @click="unlinkAccount($event.target.children[0])">
      <i class="fa fa-unlink"></i>
      Unlink
  </button>
</div>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
     unlinkAccount() {
        event.className = event.className.replace(/\bfa fa-unlink\b/g, "fa fa-spin fa-refresh");
     }
  }
}
</script>
```